# Windows to Android transfer over Wifi?

Tags: android

Please recommend a secure way to transfer files from a Windows computer to Samsung Galaxy over Wifi?

Ideally without installing a new app on the phone. Maybe the Android OS has some Wifi file transfer feature built in? If not, then I'm willing to install something from the Play store. But I would like it to be a trusted/secure app (so that it's safe).

Comment: It's kinda built in if you use adb over wi-fi for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp/3623727#3623727

Answer (score 1):

[Airdroid](https://www.airdroid.com/) does it. It doesn't depend on Windows, it will be used from a browser. To use it from Android, search for the corresponding app in PlayStore.

Unfortunately, there is no default way to do that in Android (you need an app).

Comment: That is more like a comment than an answer - unless you want to mention an app :-)  maybe something like AirMore?

Comment: @Mawg the app is Airdroid, this is the first word in my answer :)

Comment: Wow, sorry & upvote. I can only imagine that I saw the last line " there is no default way to do that in Android " and my brain missed the rest. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can share a folder on your PC, (with the items that you would like to transfer to Android in it), ensure that you are on the same network and then you can access the content from your Android device. [This article](https://www.howtogeek.com/191378/how-to-access-shared-windows-folders-on-android-ipad-and-iphone/) explains how in nice detail.

If you are looking to copy content from your PC to your Android device then you will need to install a file manager, (lots of free ones in the Android Play Store), but if you just like the idea of just streaming movies to Android you could consider running [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.en-GB.html) as a server and just connecting to it.

Other options include using Bluetooth to transfer files - [this article](https://www.lifewire.com/bluetooth-file-transfer-4147725) does a great job of comparing it to the alternatives and explaining how (even if it focuses on 2 mobile devices).

You can also move the content to a folder or folder structure that you are prepared to share and start a web server in that directory - you can then use your Android devices Web Browser to access and download the content - this can be as simple or complex *and as secure or not* as you like.

Comment: As I understand, Bluetooth is much slower than WiFi, that's why I answered about WiFi.